# redirect to the scanned link automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have implemented a qr scanner in my app using ngx-zxing module in my ionic-angular app.

After scanning I want to redirect the user to the page where the scanned link is redirecting directly without manual intervention of the user.

**code.html**

```
<!-- code for qr scanner alreday implemented, the result is present in the below code -->

<div>
<a href="{{qrResult}}" #link></a>
</div>
```

**code.ts**

```
//all imports and components are written.I am directly implementing the function definition in in which I have to redirect to the link.


handleQrCodeResult(result: string) {
    console.log("Result", result);
    this.qrResult = result;
    this.clickLink();

  }

clickLink(){
  let el = (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('link'))
    console.log('el', el); // this is returning null.
el.click();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have a look, the following code doesn't require human interaction

```
handleQrCodeResult(result: string) {
  console.log("Result", result);
  this.qrResult = result;

  // This line will redirect to the link you want
  window.location.href = "Insert link here";    // Maybe: document.getElementById('link')
}
```

> Explanation

1. `window.location.href = "URL";`
   If you assign url to this variable, the browser redirects to the url in the same page, doesn't open a new tab
2. `window.open("URL", "_blank");`
   Use this to open the url in new tab